# Is there a way to submit google forms responses to different spreadshseets, based on user dropdown choice?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have many users who submit workload data via a google from. These include a field that designates the site they are reporting from.

I now have 1000s of responses that I `query > filter` from the main response submission sheet, into separate spreadsheets for each site. The data load time for the query is getting longer and longer with the growing responses.

```
[FORM] --> [MASTER SHEET WITH RESPONSES]
                        |
                        |
                      / | \
           QUERY FILTER INTO SEPARATE SHEETS
```

I'd like to, instead, force the form to submit the responses directly into the appropriate site spreadsheet based on which site is selected in the form. Is there a way to do this?

```
[FORM: USER SITE SELECTION] --> SCRIPT SENDS DATA DIRECTLY TO SHEET FOR THAT SITE
```

Comment: Sure. You can disable sheet linking and use `onFormSubmit` trigger to submit to the correct sheet.

Comment: To further expound on @TheMaster's answer you need to add the `onFormSubmit` trigger directly to the form (**not** each spreadsheet) and process the submissions yourself. There are known issues with this approach where some some form responses do not trigger the `onFormSubmit` handler. So you may want to set ups redundancy checks where you have a time based trigger that checks the form responses to verify whether or not they were processed by the `onFormSubmit` trigger and handle the situation accordingly.

Comment: Okay, but how to I direct the form contents to be deposited within one of a dozen different spreadsheets, based on the selection of a dropdown box?

Comment: @user1837608 See the [Apps Script reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)

Comment: @sinaraheneba That's a pretty broad referral. Was there a particular section of the documentation that you were thinking of?

Comment: Why not use directly four different forms with the same content, but with different spreadsheets as destination? You can create a simple welcome web page where the user chooses his site and will be redirected accordingly to the form with corresponding destination.

Answer (score 0):

You asked whether there is a way to force a form to submit responses directly into a spreadsheet based on a form selection?

In comments `TheMaster` and `DimuDesigns` referred to i) using a script bound to the form, not the spreadsheet, and ii) using `onFormSubmit` as an installable trigger. The following answer is an example of those principles.

In testing, I found that it was essential that the form should be named `onFormSubmit(e)`. If the code is named as a custom function, then I found it gave an error "You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl."

Possibly I might/could/should have used `switch` instead of `if...else`. But there are many ways of realising this outcome, and this code should be regarded as just one example.

---

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //so5745108802
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var resp = e.response.getItemResponses();
  //Logger.log(resp);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: resp = "+resp+", and length = "+resp.length);

  var dateStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10:00", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  var output = [];
  var temp=[];
  temp.push(dateStamp);
  for (var j = 0; j < resp.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = resp[j];
    // Logger.log('DEBUG: Response to the question "%s" was "%s"',itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),itemResponse.getResponse());
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the response = "+ itemResponse.getResponse())    
    temp.push(itemResponse.getResponse());
  }
  output.push(temp);
  // Logger.log(output);
  var target = resp[2].getResponse();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target sheet is "+target)

  // Note: be sure to edit the urls for your own spreadsheets
  if (target === "A"){
    // target = A
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/url1/edit" // Spreadsheet=so_57451088_A
  }
  else if (target === "B"){
    // target = B
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/url2/edit" // Spreadsheet=so_57451088_B
  }
  else {
    // target = C
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/url3/edit" // Spreadsheet=so_57451088_C
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(sheetLR+1,1, 1, resp.length+1);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation());
  targetRange.setValues(output);
}
```

---

Form screenshot
[image: Form screenshot]

---

Example Spreadsheet screenshot
[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

---